# SIGABRT Error when running on an iOS device but not in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

The app initially loads a local webpage, I can see the below error in the log. Am I right in thinking that this means the webpage is not being copied accros to the device?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3572088f 0x33344259 0x35720789 0x357207ab 0x34abd05f 0x34abcffb 0x79145 0x32e59c8b 0x32eb963d 0x32eb95db 0x32eb8f15 0x32eb8c49 0x78bd5 0x32e58cab 0x32e527dd 0x32e20ac3 0x32e20567 0x32e1ff3b 0x3341222b 0x356f4523 0x356f44c5 0x356f3313 0x356764a5 0x3567636d 0x32e5186b 0x32e4ecd5 0x78a25 0x78628)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check the string you're passing to the URL path parameter

Comment: You are passing nil value to the `url`. Have you check the string is null or not using breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you also posted the code that created the file url.

Just looking at the error check if you have written the filename correctly when you created the URL. Simulator is key insensitive but the device is key sensitive. So on simulator x.png and X.png are the same thing but on the device they are different

Comment: This could be the case - I will have a look